# Tikzcd withing newcommand?

Tags: macros, tikz-cd

I want to define a new command using the package **tikz-cd**.

For example, suppose I want to define:

```
\newcommand{\simplearrow}[3]{\begin{tikzcd} 
#1\arrrow[r, "#3"'] & #2 \end{tikzcd}}
```

This would give an arrow #3 from #1 to #2, but it does not work.

I guess the problem has to do with the double quotes in "#3" ' (the extra ' is for positioning the label below the arrow so it is important).

How to solve this?

Thanks